# Extract substring from string if certain characters exists SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string:

```
DECLARE @UserComment AS VARCHAR(1000) = 'bjones marked inspection on system UP for site COL01545 as Refused to COD won''t pay upfront  :Routeid: 12 :Inspectionid: 55274'
```

Is there a way for me to extract everything from the string after 'Inspectionid: ' leaving me just the InspectionID to save into a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example doesn't quite work correctly. You defined your variable as varchar(100) but there are more characters in your string than that.

This should work based on your sample data.

```
DECLARE @UserComment AS VARCHAR(1000) = 'bjones marked inspection on system UP for site COL01545 as Refused to COD won''t pay upfront  :Routeid: 12 :Inspectionid: 55274'

select right(@UserComment, case when charindex('Inspectionid: ', @UserComment, 0) > 0 then len(@UserComment) - charindex('Inspectionid: ', @UserComment, 0) - 13 else len(@UserComment) end)
```

Comment: I went ahead and fixed the post.  That being said your response worked perfectly.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I would do this as:

```
select stuff(@UserComment, 1, charindex(':Inspectionid: ', @UserComment) + 14, '')
```

This works even if the string is not found -- although it will return the whole string.  To get an empty string in this case:

```
select stuff(@UserComment, 1, charindex(':Inspectionid: ', @UserComment + ':Inspectionid: ') + 14, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let me say that your @UserComment variable is not long enough to contain the text you're putting into it.  Increase the size of that first.

The SQL below will extract the value:

```
DECLARE @UserComment AS VARCHAR(1000); SET @UserComment = 'bjones marked inspection on system UP for site COL01545 as Refused to COD won''t pay upfront  :Routeid: 12 :Inspectionid: 55274'

DECLARE @pos int
DECLARE @InspectionId int
DECLARE @IdToFind varchar(100)

SET @IdToFind = 'Inspectionid: '
SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@IdToFind, @UserComment)
IF @pos > 0
BEGIN
    SET @InspectionId = CAST(SUBSTRING(@UserComment, @pos+LEN(@IdToFind)+1, (LEN(@UserComment) - @pos) + 1) AS INT)
    PRINT @InspectionId
END
```

You could make the above code into a SQL function if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If the Inspection ID is always 5 digits then the last argument for the Substring function (length) can be 5, i.e.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@UserComment,PATINDEX('%Inspectionid:%',@UserComment)+14,5)
```

If the Inspection ID varies (but is always at the end - which your question slightly implies), then the last argument can be derived by subtracting the position of 'InspectionID:' from the overall length of the string. Like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@UserComment,PATINDEX('%Inspectionid:%',@UserComment)+14,LEN(@usercomment)-(PATINDEX('%Inspectionid:%',@UserComment)+13))
```